# Wordpress and handling if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

Tags: php, wordpress

I've written a script in php which works like a charm. Now I'm trying to integrate this script in WordPress. Which is new for me.

In my php script I removed all the PDO commands as I know/think WordPress can't handle these.

I simply changed it to `$wpdb`. I did some test and this works.
The test I did were with a simple script. User input that gets submitted and gets uploaded to my database.

Now I want to make it a bit more complicated. I first want the user input to be checked for errors. The error handling is in a different php file. I know this works as I've tested it.

Where I seem to struggle is putting it all together in Wordpress.

What I did you can see below. Question is why is this not working in WordPress? Am I overlooking something?

```
<?php
include_once('scripts/useful_functions.inc.php');
global $wpdb;

if (($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== "") {

    sendmail($mail);

    $table = $wpdb->ajrecuit_com.'sollicitatie_form';
    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['afile']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['afile']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['afile']['type'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['afile']['tmp_name'];
    $folder="uploads/";
    $data = array(
        'geslacht' => $_POST['geslacht'],
        'voornaam' => $_POST['voornaam'],
        'familienaam' => $_POST['familienaam'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'tel' => $_POST['tel'],
        'afile' => rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['afile']['name'],
        'size' => $_FILES['afile']['size'],
        'type' => $_FILES['afile']['type'],
    );

    $new_size = $file_size/1024;
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    $format = array(
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s',
        '%s'
    );

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file)) {
        $success=$wpdb->insert( $table, $data, $format,$folder);
        if($success) {
            ?>

            <script>
                alert('successfully uploaded');
                window.location.href='sollicitatie_formulier_wp?success';
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }
}else { ?>

<div class="form">

    <div class="tab-content">
        <h1>Sollicitatie Formulier</h1>

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >


            <div class="top-row">
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <p><span class="error">* verplichte velden.</span></p>
                    <label>Geslacht</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $geslachtErr;?></span>
                    <select name="options[foo]">
                        <option value="" <?php selected( $options['foo'], 1 ); ?>></option>
                        <option value="Man" <?php selected( $options['foo'], 2 ); ?>>Man</option>
                        <option value="Vrouw" <?php selected( $options['foo'], 3 ); ?>>Vrouw</option>
                    </select>
                </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Voornaam</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $voornaamErr;?></span>
                    <input type="text" name="voornaam" value="">
                </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>Familienaam</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $familienaamErr;?></span>
                    <input type="text" name="familienaam" value="<?= isset($_POST['familienaam']) ? $_POST['familienaam'] : ''; ?>">
                </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->
            </div> <!-- /top-row -->

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>Email Adres</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
                <input type="email" name="email" value="<?= isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>">
            </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>Telefoon/GSM</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $telErr;?></span>
                <input type="text" name="tel" value="<?= isset($_POST['tel']) ? $_POST['tel'] : ''; ?>">
            </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

            <div class="field-wrap">
                <label>CV</label><span class="error">* <?php echo $afileErr;?></span>
                <input type="file" name="afile" >
            </div> <!-- /field-wrap-->

            <button type="submit" class="button button-block" />Get Started</button>


        </form>

    </div><!-- /tab-content-->

</div> <!-- /form -->


<?php }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Do you get any error messages? Does the code inside the if condition get executed when you submit the form? Try adding a `die("hello")` function call inside the if condition to see if that is at least returning true.

Comment: what is "$table = $wpdb->ajrecuit_com.'sollicitatie_form';"? What is the table name you are using?

Comment: @cornel.raiu, this is to make connection to my database table

Comment: "ajrecuit_com" is a method you added to WP? or?

Comment: @JoeMoe1984, where should I be adding the `die("hello")`

Comment: What is the table name you are using there?

Comment: @cornel.raiu, this has nothing to do with it. It's my db name

Comment: you have "sendmail($mail);" is the email being sent? so that we know it gets there

Comment: @JoeMoe1984, I don't get an error, it just goes to an empty wp page, with only header and footer. But the purpose of the script is when nothing is filled in it gives me error messages inside the form

Comment: Does the URL change on submit?

Comment: @cornel.raiu, no mail is being sent, so it keeps blocking at the if condition

Comment: I am adding it to one of my local installs to test without the functions include and see what the behaviour is

Comment: @cornel.raiu, no, it just goes to a blank Wordpress page with header and footer

Comment: is that the 404 error page you are landing on when you go to the blank page?

Comment: do you have any errors in the error log?

Comment: Because on my install it gets past the "if" and errors at sendmail() which is not a standard WP function. Is that one defined?

Comment: Turn DEBUG on and see if it triggers any errors

Comment: @JoeMoe1984, no not the 404 error page, just a page with header and footer with nothing between it

Comment: Also, do you want to make it upload in the standard wordpress Uploads folder? Because if that is the case you should get the upload folder using wp_upload_dir() and not the way you get it

Comment: @cornel.raiu, yes that is defined and working. how do I turn on DEBUG in WordPress?

Comment: in wp-config, switch WP_DEBUG to true: define('WP_DEBUG', true);

Comment: I guess it's either a "move_uploaded_file()" issue or a db insert issue

Comment: get the error....Undefined variable: geslachtErr....which is strange as the file that I'm calling is handling that

Comment: remove all the " && $geslachtErr== "" && $voornaamErr== "" && $familienaamErr== "" && $emailErr== "" && $telErr== "" && $afileErr== """ and test it with that

Comment: and that is not an error, but a notice. so you don't have to worry about it now. or simply replace all the $var=="" with !empty($var)

Comment: in case the "if" would be false it would display the form again. So it is going through the if and failing somewhere else ...

Comment: The error seems to be in my useful_functions.inc.php. `function selected($geslacht, $choice) {
    if($geslacht==$choice) echo "selected";
  }` It keeps blocking in my script. I think I need to adjust my main script with the select function

Comment: wordpress has a function "selected()" - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected

Comment: can you also add the contents of your "scripts/useful_functions.inc.php" file? so we can see it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress has a function "selected()" - https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected

You have to change that selected name to something else or use the Wordpress function

Comment: did you open the link? It is basically doing the same thing you are doing in your function. Plus, I see that part of your HTML, the select box to be more precise, is taken from that URL.